# Take input from yaml file in html file

Tags: javascript, html, dom, yaml

I have html code like below

```
 <div class="row <%- jsonEditor.model.form[opt.prefix].justClass('showImportForm', 'hide') %>">
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                        <label class=" col-sm-2 col-lg-2 control-label">
                            Nodename
                        </label>
                        <div class="input-group  col-sm-10 col-lg-10 col-xs-12"  >

                            <% if(opt.select2){ %>
                                <~ jsonEditor.model.isLoaded_cli_reference>
                                    <% if(jsonEditor.model.isLoaded_cli_reference){ %>
                                        <select class="form-control select2" id="new_json_name<%- opt.prefix %>" data-placeholder="Select param" >
                                            <option selected="" disabled="" value="" disabled>Not set</option>
                                            <% keys = Object.keys(jsonEditor.options[optionsblock]).sort();
                                               for(var i in keys){ %>
                                                <% if($.inArray(keys[i], opt.excluded_options) == -1){ %>
                                                    <option value="<%- keys[i] %>" >
                                                        <%- keys[i] %> (<%- jsonEditor.options[optionsblock][keys[i]].help %>)
                                                    </option>
                                                <% } %>
                                            <% } %>
                                        </select>
                                        <=js $("#new_json_name<%- opt.prefix %>").select2({ width: '100%' }) js=>
                                    <% } %>
                                <~>
                            <% }else{ %>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" id="new_json_name<%- opt.prefix %>" value=""  class="form-control" >
                            <% } %>
                            <=js jsonEditor.initForm('<%- optionsblock %>', '<%- opt.prefix %>') js=> 

                            <div class="help-block"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This looks like [image]

In the above code, I hardcoded `Nodename`. Instead, If only I could take the yaml file for reference, search for `Variable Name` and put its value (which is nodename in this case, then it would be great.

PS I did not write this code, I am using this as reference. Please let me know if any other file needed.

```
# Variable_name: nodename
# Question: Please enter the Full qualified nodename:
# Complexity: simple
# Delimiter: :
# Default: <null>
```

Is this something we can do? Do I need to use javascript here?

Comment: HTML is not a programming language. DOM is not a format. If JavaScript is the language you are using, there a a lot of templating engines available to do what you want. However, from your question it is very unclear what you actually want to do. Maybe describe a use-case with given input and expected result.

Comment: @flyx, please see if my edit helps

Comment: Your „HTML“ code has a lot of non-HTML stuff in it. I suspect this is JSP or something, but I'm not sure. please tag your question properly. Please be specific about where you want your YAML be used – at server-side (i.e. before the site is delivered to the user's browser) which would mean that the solution would be embedded in JSP, or at client-side, which would mean that you'd use JavaScript (although I consider it unlikely that you want to do that).